# How to reload a tab every 5 seconds if it is not active

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, refresh, milliseconds

Hi guys I've read a lots of similar questions but I can't find a specific solution for that.

I try this...but works only for the first reload than after the page is refresh in the background it'll not realod again alone after 5 seconds.

```
var isActive;

window.onfocus = function () { 
  isActive = true; 
}; 

window.onblur = function () { 
  isActive = false; 
}; 
setInterval(function () { 
  if (isActive == false) {location.reload();}
}, 5000);
```

Thank u.

Comment: i solve with this.... http://jsfiddle.net/wve3H

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve with this.... 
    jsfiddle.net/wve3H

Thank u to everyone

Answer (score 0):

You could try this [jquery IdleTimer plugin](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/). It seems to satisfy your requirement.

Cheers..

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of method to achieve this problem.Like.......

```
setTimeout(function(){ window.location.reload(1); }, 5000);

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" />
```